# Hive query to extract part of the field after the matching pattern

Tags: hive

Need Hive Query using `regexp_extract` to extract a part of a Field (type String). The value in it is colon separated

```
Field1 ( String)
----------------
AAA:123,BBB:345,CCC:456,DDD:789,EEE:434

AAA:343,BBB:222,DDD:989,EEE:344

BBB:233,CCC:211,DDD:888,EEE:912

Need to extract the value of BBB

Field1
-------
345

222

233
```

Tried `regexp_extract` and could not get the output as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
select regexp_extract('AAA:123,BBB:345,CCC:456,DDD:789,EEE:434', '(BBB:)([\\d]+)', 2);

345

select regexp_extract('AAA:343,BBB:222,DDD:989,EEE:344', '(BBB:)([\\d]+)', 2);

222

select regexp_extract('BBB:233,CCC:211,DDD:888,EEE:912', '(BBB:)([\\d]+)', 2);

233
```

Comment: @manchand You're welcome. If it's working and fits in your scenario, please consider accept the answer (the green tick on the left).

Answer (score 1):

Assume your table name is ***temp***, and column name is ***s*** with one string. You can use this function to get your values: `select regexp_extract(s, 'BBB:(.*?)(,)', 1) from temp;`

Comment: This is not working if  BBB is the last set in the field.